# Python, 2 dice, unable to progress (NEWBIE)

Tags: python, while-loop, dice

I'm trying to write a 'game' for 2 players: 2 dice, rolled until both dice show 6 (6 and 6 wins, 1 and 6 is a reroll of both dice etc.). I'm stuck as my code ends with any instance of rolling a 6. I can't figure out where the problem is.

Afterwards, second player rolls until two sixes show, I'll look into counting the rolls etc.

```
#double dice
import random

player1 = input("Player 1, press enter to roll the dice :  ")
a = 0
b = 0
while (a and b) != 6:   
    player1 = input("Player 1, press enter to roll the dice :  ")
    a = random.randint(1,6)
    b = random.randint(1,6)
    print("You got " + str(a) + (" and ") + str(b))
```

I've even tried adding an extra check to see if it 'rolls' 2 sixes, but doesn't actually print it - no bueno.

```
if (a and b) == 6:
    print("Awesome, you got it! " + str(a) + ("and") + str(b))
```

Googling stuff helps most of the time, but I'm still at the stage of struggling to understand what I'm looking at. Any help will be appreciated - preferably a description of the issue rather than fix in the code.

Comment: What do you think the value of `(a and b)` is?  You could use `while (a, b) != (6, 6):`

Comment: `(a and b) != 6` That is not the right way to test multiple variables against a value.